# The number of cyclic subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite non-cyclic group such that it has cyclic subgroup of order $n$. Please consider the following claim:

The number of cyclic subgroups of order $n$ in $G$ is a multiple of the greatest divisor of $|G|$ that is prime to $n$.

I have checked it for many finite groups and think must be true. But I cannot prove it. What is your idea? Thanks

Comment: $C_6$ has unique cyclic subgroups of orders $2$ and $3$. But $1$ is not a multiple of the greatest divisor of $|G|$ that is prime to $n$. Or did you mean to write FACTOR instead of MULTIPLE?

Comment: @Nick Gill: I consider only non-cyclic group.

Answer (score 4):

A counterexample to your claim: The symmetric group $S_3$ contains a unique cyclic subgroup of order 3 (the alternating group $A_3$), however 1 is not a multiple of 2 (the greatest divisor of $|S_3|=6$ that is relative prime to 3).